# Creating a quiz with points system - iPhone?

Tags: iphone, points

looking for a bit of basic info here -

I want to create a small quiz (10 questions or so), which have four possible answers for each. Rather than have a right or wrong answer I would like to have points awarded for each answer and a total score added up at the end of the quiz. Technically because there are no right or wrong answers it's not really a quiz...I'll basically be asking for a persons preference in a series of questions.

I'd very much appreciate anyone that could help me by telling me where I can start off in this, am I best using sqlite to store the answers and then get a result based on this?

Comment: StackOverflow is best meant for sharing code you're already trying and having us take a look "over your shoulder" rather than asking more open-ended questions like this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `sqlite` for storing questions and answers, and depending on your projects requirements you can store your result also in an `sqlite` table or a `.plist` or just simple display the result and do not store any result related data.

You can use [FMDB tutorial](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/836_Persisting_iOS_Application_Data_in_SQLite_Database_Using_FMDB.aspx) to create sqlite database on IOS, I would create a table called `Questions` with `q_id`, `questions(varchar)`, `question kind (varchar)` fields .

And create an`Answers`Table with `a_id`, `q_id(foreign Key)`  ,`answer(varchar)` ,`point` fields.
Here is foreign key [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) if you are not familiar with foreign keys.

Once your questions and answers are ready just use a simple tableview to display your question and answers.

To display your results, you have multiple options depending on your requirements, you can simply  display your result in a label. If you just want to display result use a `Singleton` integer to keep your point results, then when you are done with quiz just call that `Singleton` integer and display it.

If you want to store your results either just create another table in database or create a .plist

Comment: While SQLite is a great solution for a large number of items, for something as simple as 10 questions, I wouldn't recommend that or even a plist. I would simply go with a static array (of dictionaries) defined in a single header file. Past that, however, the plist option is best for range of 10-100 questions, and past that, CoreData or sqlite will serve you much better than any array will ever do.

Comment: you are right simplicity is good, but he may expend the project to 1000+ questions :) or in future he might want to analyze  results, he may want to separate question depending on question kind or he may want data mine all results etc..